# Python not reading file lines

Tags: python, file

```
file=open('in.txt','r')
print((file.readlines()).pop(20)[:-1])
for line in file:
    print(line[:-1])
```

I have this program and when I run it, it displays line 21 of my file and that's it. I don't know the technical terms for it but whenever I use '.read()' or 'readline()' or 'readlines()' and THEN try to read from the file directly, it never works, why is that? What's going on? I don't get an error code, it just doesn't display anything for the 'for' loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're opening the file here:

```
file=open('in.txt','r') # note r is default, you don't need it explicitly.
```

When you call `file.readlines` you exhaust your file handler:

```
print((file.readlines()).pop(20)[:-1])
```

Then when you attempt to iterate over the file again, it's at the end of the file, and does nothing.

You're also forgetting to close your file at the end. 
I recommend you use the context manager which takes care of closing the file automatically, and only go through the file once:

```
with open('in.txt', 'rU') as file:
    file_lines = file.readlines()
```

And then refer to the file lines in your list.

Note that I use the `rU` flag, which uses Universal Newlines mode. This will cover you cross-platform, as OS X, Windows, and Linux all have different newlines.

And instead of doing this:

```
for line in file:
    line[:-1]
```

You can strip the newlines by processing the lines with `line.rstrip()` which will remove the whitespace on the right.

Comment: So just to make sure, .rstrip() also removes new line commands? Because that's what I'm removing with that, not necessarily white space. Also, could you explain further what rU is? You're saying it's a Universal Newlines mode, but I thought it just told python that you're reading the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "reset" the file iterator:

```
file.seek(0)
for line in file:
    print(line[:-1])
```